# Reading a text file to extract coordinates in c

Tags: c

i am trying to read a text file and extract the cordinates of 'X' so that i can place then on a map
the text file is

```
10 20
9 8 X
2 3 P
4 5 G
5 6 X
7 8 X 
12 13 X
14 15 X
```

I tried multiple times but I am unable to extract the relevant data and place it in separate variables to plot
I am quite new to c and am trying to learn things so any help is appreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: You need to post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: We need to see your code (as dcp said). Also, we need a description of the input file format. Lines like: `9 8 X` appear to be coordinates for points (i.e. The point X is at `[9][8]`)? But, what is the `10 20` line at the top?

Comment: 10 20 is the grid size that i have to read out and print, that seems to work

Comment: This can't be your real code. The `else if` under the `fscanf` line should be `if`

Comment: oh wait thats my fault sorry, i have edited it

Comment: You're only using _scalar_ variables: x,y,z. So, you overwrite/destroy the prior values on each subsequent loop iteration. You [probably] need a `struct` such as: `struct point { int x; int y; int name; };` And, you'll need an array of them.

Comment: how do i implement that?

Comment: The `else` is superfluous. Your open & validate is a single operation. If the open fails, you return or handle it in a manner of your choosing. There is no need for the following `else`. All that does is clutter your code with unnecessary indention. Would recommend `fgets()` and `sscanf()` rather than `fscanf()` alone - up to you. You read the first line however you like. Then loop reading the lines with 3 values, checking whether the 3rd field is `'x'` to know whether to handle the coordinates you need.

Answer (score 0):

From my top comments, I suggested an array of point structs.

Here is your code refactored to do that.

I changed the `scanf` to use `%s` instead of `%c` for the point name. It generalizes the point name and [probably] works better with the input line because [I *think*] the `%c` would not match up correctly.

It compiles but is untested:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
    char name[8];
};

struct point *points;
int count;
int map_row;
int map_col;

void
read_data(const char *file_name)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        /* if the file opened is empty or has any issues, then show the error */
        perror("File Error");
        return;
    }

    /* get the dimensions from the file */
    fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &map_row, &map_col);
    map_row = map_row + 2;
    map_col = map_col + 2;

    while (1) {
        // enlarge dynamic array
        ++count;
        points = realloc(points,sizeof(*points) * count);

        // point to place to store data
        struct point *cur = &points[count - 1];

        if (fscanf(fp, "%d %d %s", &cur->x, &cur->y, cur->name) != 3)
            break;
    }

    // trim to amount used
    --count;
    points = realloc(points,sizeof(*points) * count);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of way to approach this. Craig has some very good points on the convenience of using a `struct` to coordinate data of different types. This approach reads with `fgets()` and parses the data you need with `sscanf()`. The benefit eliminates the risk of a *matching-failure* leaving characters unread in your input stream that will corrupt the remainder of your read from the point of matching-failure forward. Reading with `fgets()` you consume a line of input at a time, and that read is independent of the parsing of values with `sscanf()`.

Putting it altogether and allowing the filename to be provided by the first argument to the program (or reading from `stdin` by default if no argument is provided), you can do:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1024   /* if you need a constand, #define one (or more) */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  
  char buf[MAXC];           /* buffer to hold each line */
  int map_row, map_col;     /* map row/col variables */
  /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin if none provided) */
  FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
  
  if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
    perror ("file open");
    return 1;
  }
  
  /* read/validate first line saving into map_row, map_col */
  if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, fp) || 
      sscanf (buf, "%d %d", &map_row, &map_col) != 2) {
    fputs ("error: EOF or invalid map row/col data.\n", stderr);
    return 1;
  }
  
  /* loop reading remaining lines, for used as line counter */
  for (size_t i = 2; fgets (buf, MAXC, fp); i++) {
    char suffix;
    int x, y;
    
    /* validate parsing x, y, suffix from buf */
    if (sscanf (buf, "%d %d %c", &x, &y, &suffix) != 3) {
      fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid format line %zu.\n", i);
      continue;
    }
    
    if (suffix == 'X') {  /* check if line suffix is 'X' */
      printf ("%2d    %2d    %c\n", x, y, suffix);
    }
  }
  
  if (fp != stdin) {      /* close file if not stdin */
    fclose (fp);
  }
}
```

(**note:** this just illustrates the read and isolation of the values from lines with a suffix of `'X'`. Data handling, and calculations are left to you)

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in `dat/coordinates.txt` you could do:

```
$ ./bin/readcoordinates dat/coordinates.txt
 9     8    X
 5     6    X
 7     8    X
12    13    X
14    15    X
```

As Craig indicates, if you need to store your matching data, then an array of `struct` provides a great solution.